# Searching items in two lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I have two lists in python such as:

List1:

```
('C2244_LNO70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/2/8', 'CF164_LUJ70_SAR8', 'Router')
('C1723_LN270_SARM', '1/1/1', '1/1/8', 'CF164_LUJ70_SAR8', 'Router')
('CF618_JURI70_SARM', '1/1/1', '1/2/7', 'CF164_LUJ70_SAR8', 'Router')
('CF618_JURI70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/1/1', 'CF617_LJ370_SARM', 'Router')
('C2335_ODR70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/1/2', 'CF693_LAC70_SARM', 'Router')
```

List2:

```
('CF618_JURI70_SARM')
('C2335_ODR70_SARM')
('CF617_LJ370_SARM')
```

Now, I want to walk along List1 in such a way that if the values of column0 or column3 do not exist in List2, then that record shall be removed.

For example, in `List1(4,3)`, value `CF693_LAC70_SARM` does not exist in `List2`. Then row 4 could be removed from List1.

What's the best way of doing it? I tried nesting two `for`-loops with `if-else` conditions but I cannot achieve it ...

Any hint is appreciated...

Lucas

Comment: In your example, what would be removed and what would remain? If a non-matching column0 or column3 means that that entry is removed, then only the `'CF618... CF617` item would remain.

Comment: Hi @TigerhawkT3, yes, indeed, if any of the values in col0 or col3 do not match any of the items in List2, that row must be removed from List1. So, in my example only row3 `CF618...CF617` will remain from List1.

Comment: @LucasAimaretto you have *values of column0 or column3 do not exist*, that means if both don't exist, remove the tuple?

Comment: Hi @PadraicCunningham, sorry for my English! I mean: if any of of col0 or col3 values do not exist in List2, then that row must be removed! In my example only row3 should survive (`CF618 ... CF617`). In other words: both the values of col0 and col3 need to exist in List2.

Comment: @LucasAimaretto, no worries, then use and as in the second part of my answer or set.issuperset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these `list`s:

```
List1 = [('C2244_LNO70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/2/8', 'CF164_LUJ70_SAR8', 'Router'),
('C1723_LN270_SARM', '1/1/1', '1/1/8', 'CF164_LUJ70_SAR8', 'Router'),
('CF618_JURI70_SARM', '1/1/1', '1/2/7', 'CF164_LUJ70_SAR8', 'Router'),
('CF618_JURI70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/1/1', 'CF617_LJ370_SARM', 'Router'),
('C2335_ODR70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/1/2', 'CF693_LAC70_SARM', 'Router')]
List2 = [('CF618_JURI70_SARM'),
('C2335_ODR70_SARM'),
('CF617_LJ370_SARM')]
```

You can use the `in` operator to filter out the unwanted results:

```
filtered_list = [item for item in List1 if item[0] in List2 and item[3] in List2]
```

Or `set` operations:

```
List2s = set(List2)
filtered_list = [item for item in List1 if len({item[0], item[3]} & List2s) == 2]
```

In either case, this leaves us with:

```
>>> print(*filtered_list, sep='\n')
('CF618_JURI70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/1/1', 'CF617_LJ370_SARM', 'Router')
```

Comment: Thanks, @TigerhawkT3. The solution with the `in` operator worked like a charm! Regards!

Answer (score 3):

Use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) to store all the strings from the tuples in list2 and check if either subelement from each tuple is in the set:

```
l1=[('C2244_LNO70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/2/8', 'CF164_LUJ70_SAR8', 'Router'),
('C1723_LN270_SARM', '1/1/1', '1/1/8', 'CF164_LUJ70_SAR8', 'Route'),
('CF618_JURI70_SARM', '1/1/1', '1/2/7', 'CF164_LUJ70_SAR8', 'Router'),
('CF618_JURI70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/1/1', 'CF617_LJ370_SARM', 'Router'),
('C2335_ODR70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/1/2', 'CF693_LAC70_SARM', 'Router')]

l2 = [('CF618_JURI70_SARM',),
('C2335_ODR70_SARM',),
('CF617_LJ370_SARM',)]

st = {t[0] for t in l2 }

# update original list
l1[:] = [t for t in l1 if t[0] in st or t[3] in st]

print(l1)
```

Output:

```
[('CF618_JURI70_SARM', '1/1/1', '1/2/7', 'CF164_LUJ70_SAR8', 'Router'), ('CF618_JURI70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/1/1', 'CF617_LJ370_SARM', 'Router'), ('C2335_ODR70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/1/2', 'CF693_LAC70_SARM', 'Router')]
```

I presume you mean index 0 and index 3 which are the first and fourth columns.

If both ele 0 and ele 3 have to exist then use and:

```
l1[:] = [t for t in l1 if t[0] in st and t[3] in st]
```

which would leave  a single tuple which is the fourth:

```
[('CF618_JURI70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/1/1', 'CF617_LJ370_SARM', 'Router')]
```

You can also use `set.issuperset` which *tests whether every element in t is in s*:

```
l1[:] = [t for t in l1 if st.issuperset([t[0],t[3]])]

print((l1))
```

Which again would leave just the one tuple:

```
[('CF618_JURI70_SARM', '1/1/2', '1/1/1', 'CF617_LJ370_SARM', 'Router')]
```

Once your data is any reasonable size the cost of building the set will be offset by the efficient `0(1)` lookups that a set provides so your code will be `0(n)` as opposed to quadratic just using lists.

Comment: @Kasra, I think they are all single element tuples so we need to get the the strings from inside.

Comment: Thanks, @Padraic, the solution with the `in` operator worked very well!!

Comment: @LucasAimaretto, no worries, using lists means your code is quadratic so for large inputs will be way less efficient, issuperset would also work